# Pyinstaller ImportError : DLL load failed while importing win32gui

Tags: python, dll, pyinstaller, pywin32, win32gui

The program works fine including the win32gui calls but the executable gives this error

````
  File "Client.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32gui: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
[4628] Failed to execute script Client```

I am running on : 
Win 10 
Python 3.8
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was  **hidden imports**

So if someone has the same problem you need to add the missing module when building the executable as follows:

```
pyinstaller pathToYourPythonFile/script.py --onefile --hidden-import theMissingModule
```

For my case the missing module was **win32gui**. After fixing it, it was another one: **screenshot_every** from **[d3dshot](https://pypi.org/project/D3DShot/)** library

So basically you will face this problem if it was a **sub import** aka :

`from d3dshot import screenshot_every`

so screenshot_every is the hidden import ( you will need to do this to **reduce** the **.exe** size )

Comment: i tried ```pyinstaller pathToYourPythonFile/script.py --onefile --hidden-import win32gui``` but still the error persist. Can you please elaborate more on how you fixed your problem with ```win32gui```?

Comment: @KlienMenard post a question with details so we can help you

Comment: --hidden-import unrecognized argument?

Comment: @Klh same post your question with details

Answer (score 0):

`Win32gui` isn't compatible with `python-3.7` or above

`python-3.7` was released in 2018 and the latest version of `win32gui` was released in August 2017.

Install `pywin32`. That gives you `win32gui`

```
$pip install pywin32
import win32api
```

Comment: I'm using win32gui from pywin32 which works fine running the python file directly in PyCharm, however, upon building the project into an exe, it throws this error when starting the program. I don't quite understand how I'm able to "import win32gui" instead of doing something intuitive like "import pywin32" or "from pywin32 import win32gui" - Win32gui has been the worst experience trying to figure out.